# What is missing in the CMakeLists.txt / my library installation?

Tags: cmake, glew

I reduced my prog to the minimum just to show the pb: cmake does not complain, neither make (running Linux / libglew 1.5 / cmake 2.8.2). The program segfaults, and I have no clue why / which steps I should now make to solve the pb.

Source of render.cpp:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#ifndef WIN32
#include <GL/glx.h>
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Before init" << endl;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    cout << "After init" << endl;
    if (err != GLEW_OK)
        cout << "Initialization error" << endl;
    else{        
        cout << "Successful init" << endl;
        assert(glCreateShader);
        GLuint f = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    }
}
```

The content of CMakeList is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (render)
IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
    "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++0x")
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)

# Some directory shortcuts
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/conf)

INCLUDE(FindOpenGL REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(FindGLEW REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})

message(${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
message(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR})
message(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(render render.cpp)
target_link_libraries(render ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

As mentioned, it compiles and segfaults at the call to **glewInit()**. I have no idea what to search for at this point..
Any help would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful to anyone, I solved it: using openGL, you need to create a context before being able to call glewInit(). This can be done using the SDL library (simplifies this task). Have a look at [this](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-opengl-tutorial-basics/#more-435) tutorial.